# phonegap installation error in ubuntu

Tags: cordova, phonegap-cli

I want to install the Phonegap on my Ubuntu15.10 os but after executing phonegap installation i got the following error :

```
  npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-19-generic

  npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g"    "phonegap"

  npm ERR! node v5.6.0

  npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0

  npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/balanced-match-45910c53

  npm ERR! code ENOENT

  npm ERR! errno -2

  npm ERR! syscall rename


  npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/balanced-match-45910c53' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/balanced-match'

  npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/balanced-match-45910c53' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/balanced-match'

  npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

  npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.

  npm ERR! enoent 

  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

  npm ERR!     /home/aarzoo/npm-debug.log

 npm ERR! code 1
```

Please help to me resolve this issues as I am beginner.

Comment: Please check to here http://dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797/

Comment: I am following the same link content but getting above mention errors.

Comment: on which command you got error

Comment: I overcome this situation and successfully install phonegap. For that I did the following task:


First of all, removed all previous installed list as per follow:

sudo apt-get remove nodejs

sudo apt-get remove npm

sudo apt-get remove ant

sudo npm remove -g phonegap

and after that I perform the fresh installation and its worked for me without any errors.


Thanks Santosh Shinde for reply!

Comment: Congratulation and thanks for your interest in hybrid mobile application development.

Comment: If you got solution please accept the my answer

Answer (score 0):

First remove the all previous install application with following command and try to with once again by following this [link](http://dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797/).

```
   sudo apt-get remove <<application_name>>
```

Here **application_name** replace by your install application name.

Please if any issues comment to here.

Hope this will help You.